# Python. генерация config-файла

Tags: python

Добрый день! Есть код вида:

```
 from configobj import ConfigObj
 spec = """
 example = boolean(default=True)
 [section1]
 value1 = [value1]
 value2 = integer(default=15)
 """

 from StringIO import StringIO
 config = ConfigObj(configspec=StringIO(spec))

 from validate import Validator
 config.validate(Validator(), copy=True)
 config.filename = 'test.conf.sample'
 config.write()
```

Собственно вопрос: как при конфига генерации подставить свои переменные, чтобы было примерно так:

```
 example = boolean(default=True)
 TEST
 value1 = test
 value2 = integer(default=15)
```

Пытался сделать так

```
config['section1'] = 'TEST'
config['value1'] = "test"
```

Но ничего не работает, в чём может быть проблема? Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Попробуй сделать `config.write()` после изменения параметров.

Comment: это куда?  config.write() после




     spec = """
 example = boolean(default=True)
 [section1]
 value1 = [value1]
 value2 = integer(default=15)
 """

Comment: Я просто комментарий не понял.

Answer (score 1):

Для изменения секций/ключей, можно использовать функцию `walk`, в которую передается функция, вызываемая для каждой секции/ключа, а вот в этой функции уже можно определить логику изменений:

```
from configobj import ConfigObj
try:
    from StringIO import StringIO
except ImportError:
    from io import StringIO
from validate import Validator


def transform(section, key):
    val = section[key]
    newkey = key.replace('section1', 'TEST')

    section.rename(key, newkey)
    if isinstance(val, (tuple, list, dict)):
        pass
    else:
        try:
            val = val.replace('section1', 'TEST')
            section[newkey] = val
        except:
            pass


spec = """\
example = boolean(default=True)
[section1]
value1 = [value1]
value2 = integer(default=15)
"""

config = ConfigObj(configspec=StringIO(spec))
config.validate(Validator(), copy=True)
config.filename = 'test.conf.sample'

config['section1']['value1'] = "test yeah!"
config.walk(transform, call_on_sections=True)
config.write()

print(open(config.filename).read())
```

Консоль:

```
example = True
[TEST]
value2 = 15
value1 = test yeah!
```